# ASP.net chart with bar and line series

Tags: asp.net, charts

This is my first post, so I apologize in advance if I screw it up. I need to use the ASP.NET Chart control to display a chart with a bar series AND a line series. Here is the markup from my first attempt:

```
   <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
                                <Series>
                                    <asp:Series Name="Touches" ChartType="Bar">
                                        <Points>
                                            <asp:DataPoint YValues="20"  />
                                            <asp:DataPoint YValues="10"  />
                                            <asp:DataPoint YValues="30" />
                                        </Points>
                                    </asp:Series>
                                    <asp:Series Name="Goal" ChartType="Line">
                                        <Points>
                                            <asp:DataPoint XValue="10"    YValues="18" />
                                            <asp:DataPoint XValue="30" YValues="18" />
                                        </Points>
                                    </asp:Series>

                                </Series>
                                <ChartAreas>
                                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                                </ChartAreas>
                            </asp:Chart>
```

It produces the following error on page load:

> Chart Area Axes - The chart area contains incompatible chart types.
>   For example, bar charts and column charts cannot exist in the same
>   chart area.

Comment: Well, the error message says it all.... Perhaps you're looking for a `Column` chart type, not `Bar`.

Comment: Thank you. Using a Column chart type worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it, thank you.